# Facebook Page get_stream With Facebook Offline Validation Process?

Tags: php, api, facebook

So I am looking to make a php application similar to the fanbox, but I need to just have the data extracted as json or whatever the FBAPI returns with get_stream.  But I don't want it per-user.  I just need to grab a single fanpage wall content and put it on the website.  Would I have to validate?  How do you validate with the offline_access privileges?

Basically something that acts like an RSS feed to the Fanpage wall stream.  But how do I get there without having to validate every time?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer on a blog:

http://blog.jylin.com/2009/10/01/loading-wall-posts-using-facebookstream_get/

Just give your application the permissions, make a infinite key, then you can load the streams in from fan pages acting like your the viewer.